# I've just installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and cannot find the link "Software" to download more. How do I get this link back?

Tags: 20.04

This is my 2nd laptop installation of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and the first has this link under "System" on the "start menu" but the link for "software" didn't install or somehow has been deleted on this second install. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It appears that "Software" has been replaced with "Snap Store" in the latest update, and the store now only contains snaps anymore. Noticed the same thing yesterday, not too happy about it. Note that you still have the possibility to install from the repositories using apt if you know what you need.

Comment: I have Snap store installed and it contains/can install both regular deb packages and snap apps as well. Snap Store is supposed to give users more control while installing snap apps but it's still not complete. I hope they fix it soon. By the meantime you can easily install gnome-software either by using Terminal or from within the Snap Store itself.

Comment: Thanks! The first laptop I installed on was done on the second day that was available and I guess TPTB had not changed the link name yet.